# Assigning Enum to Field of Implemented TypeScript Class

Tags: typescript, enums, constructor, implements, incompatibility

Let's say we have an enum, "Profession":

```
enum Profession {
  Teacher = "Teacher",
  Scientist = "Scientist",
  Rapper = "Rapper",
}
```

And we have a `Person` interface, which accepts a generic drawn from `Profession`'s values:

```
interface Person<P extends Profession> {
  profession: P;
}
```

And finally, we want to implement `Person`:

```
class AmericanCitizen implements Person<Profession.Teacher> {
  // ... problem continued below
}
```

... within the class implementation, I'd like to assign the generic-specified `profession` like so:

```
class AmericanCitizen implements Person<Profession.Teacher> {
  profession = Profession.Teacher;
}
```

This results in the following TS error:

```
Property 'profession' in type 'AmericanCitizen' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Person<Profession.Teacher>'.
  Type 'Profession' is not assignable to type 'Profession.Teacher'.
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACgTgewGbAM6oJYJFA3gWACgooAVYAQwGMALYOKAXigCJzq64WAaIkgZSoZQAFwyoRTVoOEgxEnnygAlCgAc19KS1Ub6iwgF8iRDHPpJqwWPVTYAPDCjAAHiNAATVLEQp0WEAA+PCU1XzRMbAAuWABuImNCIioAGwp0KABBCHoMKgoQAGEMMQAvUCgMCDUU4By5bxhbB3hkCICAOnZaemCCYigwtv9sKVa-SJAuyh64eKMgA)

The compiler forces me to do the long-hand equivalent:

```
class AmericanCitizen implements Person<Profession.Teacher> {
  profession: Profession.Teacher;

  constructor() {
    this.profession = Profession.Teacher;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACgTgewGbAM6oJYJFA3gWACgooAVYAQwGMALYOKAXigCJzq64WAaIkgZSoZQAFwyoRTVoOEgxEnnygAlCgAc19KS1Ub6iwgF8iRDHPpJqwWPVTYAPDCjAAHiNAATVLEQp0WEAA+PCU1XzRMbAAuWABuImNCIioAGwp0KABBCHoMKgoQAGEMMQAvUCgMCDUU4By5bxhbB3hkCICAOnZaemCCYigwtv9on2HIkC7KHrh4pIGqbAk4MCoRBDgACgBKEIGSERpxDqG-CalWs87uzjmSRMMgA)

Why is it that the former is invalid?

Comment: Doing `profession = Profession.Teacher as Profession.Teacher` works for some reason as well ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=2#code/KYOwrgtgBACgTgewGbAM6oJYJFA3gWACgooAVYAQwGMALYOKAXigCJzq64WAaIkgZSoZQAFwyoRTVoOEgxEnnygAlCgAc19KS1Ub6iwgF8iRDHPpJqwWPVTYAPDCjAAHiNAATVLEQp0WEAA+PCU1XzRMbAAuWABuImNCIioAGwp0KABBCHoMKgoQAGEMMQAvUCgMCDUU4By5bxhbB3hkCICAOnZaemCCYigwtv9sKVa-SJAuyh6GdJ9hyemOenijIA)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class AmericanCitizen implements Person<Profession.Teacher> {
  profession = Profession.Teacher;
}
```

Since you haven't told typescript what type you want `profession` to be, typescript will try to infer it from how you're using it. It sees you're assigning `Profession.Teacher` to it, which is part of an enum so it assumes you want `profession` to be that enum. Not a specific *value* of the enum though; the whole thing. Similarly if you tried to define `name = "bob"` it would assume you wanted `string` as the type, not specifically "bob", and `age = 100` would be `number`, not specifically 100.

You can tell typescript that you want something more specific in several ways:

```
profession: Profession.Teacher = Profession.Teacher;
```

```
profession = Profession.Teacher as Profession.Teacher;
```

```
profession = Profession.Teacher as const;
```

Your version with a constructor works too and is equivalent to my first example.

Comment: Thank you for the fast & high quality response!